# Migrate SVN to GitHub with Selected Branches

Tags: git, git-svn

I want to migrate a project from SVN to GitHub.

The structure of the SVN project is:

```
Project URL
    trunk
        application1
        application2
        application3
    branches
        version1.0
            application1
            application2
            application3
        version2.0
            application1
            application2
            application3
        version3.0
            application1
            application2
            application3
        version4.0
            application1
            application2
            application3
```

What I want to have on GitHub is four folders:

```
application1
    master 
    version1.0
    version2.0
    version3.0
    version4.0
application2
    master 
    version1.0
    version2.0
    version3.0
    version4.0
application3
    master 
    version1.0
    version2.0
    version3.0
    version4.0
application4
    master 
    version1.0
    version2.0
    version3.0
    version4.0
```

I tried using the command (for one application):

```
git svn clone --username $username  --trunk=trunk/application1                  
      --branches=braches/version1/application1    --branches=braches/version2/application1   --branches=braches/version3/application1  
--branches=braches/version4/application1 
 --authors-file=authors_modified.txt  $svnURL   application1    --no-metadata`
```

But I got the error

```
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): 
Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 100, path '/branches'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn
 is just searching aggressively for old history.
```

If this migration is feasible, if yes, what's wrong here?

Comment: In my experience, that's normal output from git-svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert your complex tree with SubGit, not git-svn
2. Perform *conversion per application* in a time, not in one huge step

Comment: We only aim for one-way migration, and we will not use SVN anymore. So is there way to fulfill the goal in the question and without installing anything on the Git server? We are using the Enterprise GitHub so there are many restrictions.

Comment: @RayZheng - you **can** use SubGit for [ migration](https://subgit.com/documentation/import-book.html), installing on git-server needed only on using in bridge-mode